How do i specify index_name in llama-index MilvusVectorStore
I'm working on a python rag project. where I'm using milvus as vector database and using llama-index for setting up the project.
I have done setting up milvus database, wrote code for embedding the documents, in milvus collection i have created a schema and added 3 indexes among those 2 are scalar indexes and one is a vector index.
def _create_indexes(self, collection: Collection):
    """Create indexes on the collection"""
    try:
        collection.drop_index()  # Clear any existing indexes
    except Exception as e:
        logger.warning(f"No existing indexes to drop: {e}")

    collection.create_index(field_name="account_id", index_name="account_id_index")
    collection.create_index(field_name="file_id", index_name="file_id_index")

    index_params = {
        "index_type": "IVF_FLAT",
        "metric_type": "IP",
        "params": {"nlist": self.config.nlist},
    }
    collection.create_index(
        field_name="embedding",
        index_params=index_params,
        index_name="embedding_index",
    )
    collection.load()

Milvus is getting populated, all 3 indexes are also getting created.
After this, for doing the search i was trying to create an instance of MilvusVectorStore
in the following way.
self._store = MilvusVectorStore(
    uri=self.config.uri,
    collection_name=collection_name,
    dim=self.config.embedding_dim,
    similarity_metric="IP",
    embedding_field="embedding",
    index_name="embedding_index",
    search_config={
        "metric_type": "IP",
        "params": {"nprobe": self.config.nprobe},
        "index_name": "embedding_index",
    },
    index_config={
        "field_name": "embedding",
        "index_type": "IVF_FLAT",
        "metric_type": "IP",
        "params": {"nlist": self.config.nlist},
        "index_name": "embedding_index",
    },
)

but, since I have multiple indexes, I'm getting the following error
 pymilvus.decorators - ERROR - RPC error: [describe_index], <AmbiguousIndexName: (code=1, message=There are multiple indexes, please specify the index_name.)>, <Time:{'RPC start': '2024-12-17 17:24:17.551945', 'RPC error': '2024-12-17 17:24:17.584774'}>

It looks like I'm making some mistake in initializing the MilvusVectorStore instance, specifically the params index_config and search_config.
I don't know how should i specify the index_name during this process(that's what error says). can anybody help ?
